# manipulating javascript date object

Tags: javascript

I know with a java calendar, you can go back to a previous date, but how do I do that with a javascript date? Lets say I want to go backwards three months, how do I do that? I'm assuming that there has to be some logic to do that, and not just do a setMonth(), since rolling back 3 months may take you back to the previous year, and so the year needs to be updated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use one of the date libraries such as date.js

http://datejs.com

`Date.add(-3).month();`

Comment: date.js is good, but note that it has been abandoned: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/datejs/info

Answer (score 0):

[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) is a JavaScript library that is great for date manipulation.  Using MomentJS, you could do something like:

```
// Subtract 3 months from the current moment (now)
moment().subtract('months', 3);
```

If you must use the JavaScript Date object, you can use the setMonth() but it can be unreliable (as you mentioned).  As an example:

```
// Get the next and previous month from now (first day of the month)
var now = new Date();
var futureMonth = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1, 1);
var pastMonth = now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - 1, 1);
```

Note that you need to specify the second parameter to set the day to 1.  This will prevent the "next" month from skipping a month (e.g. adding a month to January 31, 2014 will result in March 3rd, 2014 if you omit the second parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Any rollover date manipulation to a new period (ie new year, month, week, day, etc) is handled automatically

```
var d = new Date();
    -> Tue Oct 01 2013 14:12:21 GMT+1000 (EST)

d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
    -> Mon Jul 01 2013 14:13:43 GMT+1000 (EST)

d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 10);
    -> Sat Sep 01 2012 14:14:31 GMT+1000 (EST)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using get month you can get the value from 0-11,so if you want to go back to 3 months just chekc if month no. is greater than 3 ,if it is greater than 3 no need to change the year,else decrement the year by 1

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't need to worry about roll backing the year.  Just set the month and remaining it with JS rendering machine.

```
var date = new Date();
date.setMonth(-10); //+ increase the month or - decrease
alert(date);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/KmHVE/1/)

Comment: `-10` isn't going to minus 10 months from the current one

Comment: @Phil Yes right.  I just to show him an example that rollback the month will automatically take care of the year.  `-3 => July 2013`.  Hope you got my point.